# Ember JS preferred way to access ember object properties

Tags: ember.js

What is the preferred way to access properties of ember objects? I often see the the .get() method being used, but wonder why people don't just use dot notation instead. For example in [Advice in the Use of Ember](http://trek.github.com/) Mr. Trek writes the following:

```
connectOutlets: function(router) {
  router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('myView');
}
```

However, the following works just as well in ember-1.0.0-pre.2.min.js (not sure version matters in this case):

```
connectOutlets: function(router) {
  router.applicationController.connectOutlet('myView');
}
```

Is there a difference? Or is it a matter of personal taste?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bare property access will only work on browsers that support `Object.defineProperty` https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-metal/lib/accessors.js#L35

Comment: Brilliant, figured there was something to it. Thanks! I'll try diving into the source next time, still hacking my way through ember.  Also thanks for your [article](http://trek.github.com/) it has been the biggest help thus far.

Comment: Is this still true - that .get is preferred?  Or should I expect that Ember polyfills for property access with dot notation?

Comment: .get is still required. There is no way to polyfill this back to all the supported browser for Ember.